# How can I add a spring-based project as a Maven dependency in another project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I created Project A from spring initalizr, the pom.xml looks essentially like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ProjectA</name>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- [...] many more Spring and non-spring related dependencies -->

</dependencies>

    <!--  org.springframework.boot plugin, repositories and plugin repos here -->
```

This is a standalone project, in the sense that it is able to run from a main class as a Spring app. This is very useful for testing purposes.

I want to be able to use Project A as part of another project (Project B) - that is - another Spring application should scan all of the beans of ProjectA in addition to its own. ProjectA also has some files in the /resources folder which need to remain available. (Ideally, these would end up in the root of the final executable jar).

I tried installing PrA (IntelliJ has a handy **intall** option under the Maven menu) it in my local repository and adding it as a dependency in **Project B**, but that imports neither its own dependencies (so spring annotations in project B won't work) nor its classes. Specifying the dependency type as `pom` fixed the first issue but not the second.

Now, **Project B** can use all of project A's dependencies without having to import them.
However, no classes of project A can be either seen, scanned or even imported in project B.

**What am I doing wrong?** Sorry, Maven is still very obscure to me.

I have tried:

- Setting Project A as parent - nothing changes
- Invalidating caches
- Maven update
- Checking .m2 folder - Project A is correctly there
- Removing the `<build></>` portion of pom.xml in PA. It changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Jar file generated by `spring boot` it is executable fat jar.

It contains `spring boot` loader, all application dependencies, application configuration and of course application classes but in special directory visible for `spring boot` loader only.

Original jar is preserved as a copy in `target/project-version.jar.original`
You can compare output of:

```
jar --list --file=target/project-version.jar.original
jar --list --file=target/project-version.jar
```

So simply you can not use `spring boot` application as dependencies.

In order to share some code between two `spring boot` application you should create another project - **standard jar - not spring boot application** with shared staff and use it as dependencies in both application.